# DISTINCT/GROUP BY with wildcard. SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, ip

My table looks something like this:

```
ip
192.168.1.1
192.168.1.2
192.168.1.3
192.168.1.4
192.168.1.5
(...)
192.168.1.254
```

I am trying to achieve a single result from the table telling me what classes I have in my database (for example for address 192.168.1.1 result is 192.168.1.0/24 or just 192.168.1.0).

Is this possible to do using that database?

Comment: I'm assuming by "classes" you're referring to http://www.vlsm-calc.net/ipclasses.php, you should probably point that out if that's the case, or correct if not.  If it is the case you only pointed out a single class.  A dataset that encompasses more than a single class, as well as what your expected result could help others better understand your question.

Comment: I'm actually referring to anything. Trying to ignore everything after 192.168.1. and get a value that's same for all addresses from 192.168.1.0/24

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do something like this:

```
SELECT  concat(LEFT(ipAddress, LENGTH(ipAddress) - LOCATE('.', REVERSE(ipAddress))), '.0') as ipClassThing, 
        count(1) as numberInClassTypeThing
FROM    test t
GROUP   BY LEFT(ipAddress, LENGTH(ipAddress) - LOCATE('.', REVERSE(ipAddress)))
```

See [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/a88ea/12)

Basically in the above, we're looking for the last occurrence of `.`, taking only the portion of the string preceeding it, and then tacking a `.0` on the end.

With the sample data/table:

```
create table test (ipaddress varchar(50));

insert into test (ipaddress) values ('192.168.1.1');
insert into test (ipaddress) values ('192.168.1.0');
insert into test (ipaddress) values ('192.168.1.55/24');
insert into test (ipaddress) values ('10.1.1.1');
```

The above query gives the result:

```
ipClassThing    numberInClassTypeThing
----
10.1.1.0        1
192.168.1.0     3
```

Comment: Working as expected. Thank you.